# Как сделать команду, которая будет отображать количество пользователей? Database.countusers() missing 1 required positional argument: 'active'

Tags: python, sqlite, telegram, aiogram, sqlite3

У меня есть телеграм бот написанный на python, также есть база данных на sqlite3. Выглядит примерно так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Также есть команда которая по идее должна подсчитывать количество пользователей со значением 1 (countusers). Но она не работает. Когда я пытаюсь выполнить `print(message.chat.id, db.countusers())` Пишет ошибку `TypeError: Database.countusers() missing 1 required positional argument: 'active'`

Если я пишу `print(db.countusers(user_id, active))` пишет ошибку `NameError: name 'user_id' is not defined`

Не могу понять как решить эту проблему. Файл с db командами находится в отдельном файле. файл main не получает от файла db user_id и active?

Вот весь код из файла db:

```
import sqlite3

class Database:
    def __init__(self, db_file):
        self.connection = sqlite3.connect(db_file)
        self.cursor = self.connection.cursor()
    
    def user_exists(self, user_id):
        with self.connection:
            result = self.cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `user_id` = ?", (user_id,)).fetchmany(1)
            return bool(len(result))
    
    def add_user(self, user_id):
        with self.connection:
            return self.cursor.execute("INSERT INTO `users` (`user_id`) VALUES (?)", (user_id,))
    
    def set_active(self, user_id, active):
        with self.connection:
            return self.cursor.execute("UPDATE `users` SET `active` = ? WHERE `user_id` = ?", (active, user_id,))
    
    def get_users(self):
        with self.connection:
            return self.cursor.execute("SELECT `user_id`, `active` FROM `users`").fetchall()
        
    def countusers(self, active):
        with self.connection:
            return self.cursor.execute("SELECT COUNT (active) from users where active='1'").fetchall()
```

Comment: [SELECT COUNT](http://2sql.ru/novosti/sql-count/)?

Comment: `return self.cursor.execute("SELECT COUNT (active) from users where active='1'").fetchall()` правильно написал эту строчку?

Comment: когда пытаюсь использовать count_users (назвал так команду в db) в print() пишет ошибку `<bound method Database.count_users of <db.Database object at 0x0476C6D0>>`, что я сделал не так?

Comment: возможно, так: `SELECT count(*) FROM \`users\` WHERE \`active\`=1`. Но проверить не могу

Comment: ```def count_users(): return``` даже с вот такой командой, когда пишу `print(db.count_users)` пишет ошибку <bound method Database.count_users of <db.Database object at 0x04BED630>>. Что она означает? Что делать?

Comment: Это не ошибка. Вы распечатали сам метод. Чтобы вызвать метод, надо добавить скобки: `print(db.count_users())`

Comment: `print(db.count_users())` `def count_users(self, user_id, active):         with self.connection:             return self.cursor.execute("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users WHERE active = 1")` написал так. пишет ошибку: TypeError: count_users() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'user_id' and 'active'

Comment: если пишу `print(db.count_users(user_id, active))` пишет NameError: name 'user_id' is not defined. файл с db командами находится в отдельном файле. файл main не получает от файла db user_id и active?

Comment: я бы предложил вам отредактировать вопрос, разместив актуальный код в объеме, достаточном для воспроизведения ошибки

Comment: сделал, изменил вопрос

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

**В классе**

```
class Database:
#... 
    def count_users(self):
        return self.connection.cursor().execute("SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT user_id) FROM `users` WHERE `active` = 1").fetchone()[0]
#...
```

**Вне класса**

```
print(f'В базе данных {db.count_users()} активных уникальных пользователей')
```

Comment: Спасибо большое! Заработало

Answer (score 0):

Запрос на подсчёт активных пользователь может выглядеть так:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users WHERE active = 1
```

Если Вам необходимо подсчитать вообще все поля в таблице:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users
```

Возможно Вам будет полезно, в SQLite studio можно открыть редактор и там вводить необходимые запросы, где можно посмотреть их результат. **ALT + E**

Comment: Исходная таблица странная. Мне почему-то кажется, придётся писать `count(DISTINCT user_id)`.

Comment: `print(db.count_users())` `def count_users(self, user_id, active):
        with self.connection:
            return self.cursor.execute("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users WHERE active = 1")` написал так. пишет ошибку: TypeError: count_users() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'user_id' and 'active'

Comment: если пишу `print(db.count_users(user_id, active))` пишет NameError: name 'user_id' is not defined. файл с db командами находится в отдельном файле. файл main не получает от файла db user_id и active?